# How can I return true or false if create or update in loop finished on the laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

My script like this :

```
public function synch($apiItems)
{
    $itemsLocal = $this->item->get();
    foreach ($apiItems as $key) {
        $check = $itemsLocal->filter(function ($item) use ($key) {
            return $item->code == $key->Code;
        });
        if ($check->count() < 1) {
            $this->item->create([
                'code' => $key->Code,
                'description' => $key->Description,
                'attribute_code' => $key->Attribute_Code,                
                'flag' => $key->Flag
            ]);
        } 
        else {
            if($key->Flag === false) {
                $this->item->where(['code' => $check->first()->code])->update([
                    'description' => $key->Description,
                    'attribute_code' => $key->Attribute_Code,
                    'flag' => $key->Flag
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want when the create or update process is complete it will return true. and if it fails, it will return false

How can I do it?

Comment: What does it mean **fails**, I read your code but its not clear, do you mean when it throws an Exception? **Note**: you can use [`->where('code', $key->Code)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-where) instead of `filter(...)`.

Comment: @Success Man Yeah. I mean fails is if there is an error during the create or update process

Comment: @Kyslik So I want that function to return a value if the process is complete

Comment: Just use [try / catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an error when Eloquent saves changes to the database, an exception will be thrown. You can simply wrap your code with **try/catch** and return false when exception was thrown.

```
public function synch($apiItems)
{
  try {

    // your code goes here

    return true;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Note:** As you're doing multiple updates within a loop, make sure the whole process happens as a part of a single database transaction, so that you don't end up with data that is partially updated. An example would be when some items got created, but then error occurred and the rest was skipped.

Comment: The note is very important! In order to keep the integrity of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Add try catch in your code. Change such as:

```
public function synch($apiItems)
{
    try{
        $itemsLocal = $this->item->get();
        foreach ($apiItems as $key) {
            $check = $itemsLocal->filter(function ($item) use ($key) {
                return $item->code == $key->Code;
            });
            if ($check->count() < 1) {
                $this->item->create([
                    'code' => $key->Code,
                    'description' => $key->Description,
                    'attribute_code' => $key->Attribute_Code,                
                    'flag' => $key->Flag
                ]);
            } 
            else {
                if($key->Flag === false) {
                    $this->item->where(['code' => $check->first()->code])->update([
                        'description' => $key->Description,
                        'attribute_code' => $key->Attribute_Code,
                        'flag' => $key->Flag
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```